# How to move a particular app to a specific display programmatically

Tags: macos, cocoa, macos-big-sur

I need to move a particular running application to a specific display.

First of all I get a list of running apps with

```
let workspace = NSWorkspace.shared
let apps = workspace.runningApplications
  .filter{  $0.activationPolicy == .regular }
```

if I print apps I get something like

```
▿ 6 elements
  - 0 : <NSRunningApplication: 0x6000021fa480 (com.apple.Safari - 608) LSASN:{hi=0x0;lo=0xc00c}>
  - 1 : <NSRunningApplication: 0x6000021fa500 (com.apple.dt.Xcode - 610) LSASN:{hi=0x0;lo=0xd00d}>
  - 2 : <NSRunningApplication: 0x6000021fa600 (com.apple.Preview - 625) LSASN:{hi=0x0;lo=0x10010}>
  - 3 : <NSRunningApplication: 0x6000021fb280 (com.apple.finder - 629) LSASN:{hi=0x0;lo=0x2f02f}>
  - 4 : <NSRunningApplication: 0x6000021f3480 (org.mozilla.firefox - 9202) LSASN:{hi=0x0;lo=0x75075}>
```

Suppose Preview is on monitor 2 on the right and I want to move it to monitor 1 on the left.

How do I do that on BigSur?

Comment: Do the displays have separate spaces?

Comment: yes.............

Comment: I don't have an answer, but you'll likely need to use the accessibility framework (which will require user permission for your app to control the UI of another app). There is no direct way for one app to change the UI of another app.

Comment: I did that a few weeks ago using AppleScript. Now I would like to do it in Swift...